# Vectorized and Non vectorized functions + Benchmark application in R

Tags: r, function, vectorization, benchmarking

Can someone explain to me the difference between a vectorized and a non-vectorized functions based on the examples of implementation above. ?
I used the 4 methods (for loop, map, apply, vectorize) to vectorize the function.

I also have another question regarding the benchmark(), I have read that there is no need to set.seed() before applying it to asses the performance of every function. However, I can not interpret my results because every time I run it it gives me a different value.

Especially with last vectorized function I implement, I can not compare to the 4 methods above because I have different values.

PS : Even when I used the set.seed it gives different values.

Can you please help me ? Thank you so much :)

Here is my code (no data required) :

```
#non-vectorized function 
glass_champagne_non_vectorized <- function(x) {
  if (!is.numeric(x)) {
    stop("Input must be numeric", call. = FALSE)
  }

  result <- numeric(length(x))

  result[x < 0] <- 0
  result[x >= 0 & x < 0.5] <- 15
  result[x >= 0.5 & x < 10] <- 2
  result[x >= 10 & x < 15] <- 8 * log2(x[x >= 10 & x < 15] - 9) + 2
  result[x >= 15 & x < 20] <- 8 * log2(6) + 2
  result[x >= 20] <- 0

  return(result)
}

#vectorized function using for loop 
glass_champagne_for_loop <- function(x) {
  if (!is.numeric(x)) {
    stop("Input must be numeric", call. = FALSE)
  }
  result <- numeric(length(x))

  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (x[i] < 0) {
      result[i] <- 0
    } else if (x[i] >= 0 & x[i] < 0.5) {
      result[i] <- 15
    } else if (x[i] >= 0.5 & x[i] < 10) {
      result[i] <- 2
    } else if (x[i] >= 10 & x[i] < 15) {
      result[i] <- 8 * log2(x[i] - 9) + 2
    } else if (x[i] >= 15 & x[i] < 20) {
      result[i] <- 8 * log2(6) + 2
    } else if (x[i] >= 20) {
      result[i] <- 0
    }
  }
  return(result)
}



# vectorized function using map_dbl()
glass_champagne_map <- function(x) {
  if (!is.numeric(x)) {
    stop("Input must be numeric", call. = FALSE)
  }

  map_dbl(x, function(val) {
    if (val < 0) {
      return(0)
    } else if (val >= 0 & val < 0.5) {
      return(15)
    } else if (val >= 0.5 & val < 10) {
      return(2)
    } else if (val >= 10 & val < 15) {
      return(8 * log2(val - 9) + 2)
    } else if (val >= 15 & val < 20) {
      return(8 * log2(6) + 2)
    } else if (val >= 20) {
      return(0)
    }
  })
}

#vectorized function using sapply 
glass_champagne_sapply <- function(x) {
  if (!is.numeric(x)) {
    stop("Input must be numeric", call. = FALSE)
  }

  sapply(x, function(val) {
    if (val < 0) {
      return(0)
    } else if (val >= 0 & val < 0.5) {
      return(15)
    } else if (val >= 0.5 & val < 10) {
      return(2)
    } else if (val >= 10 & val < 15) {
      return(8 * log2(val - 9) + 2)
    } else if (val >= 15 & val < 20) {
      return(8 * log2(6) + 2)
    } else if (val >= 20) {
      return(0)
    }
  })
}

#vectorize using Vectorize 
glass_champagne_vectorized <- Vectorize(FUN = glass_champagne_for_loop, vectorize.args = "x")



#performance comparision 

x <- 10^(1:4)
set.seed(123)
benchmark_results <-  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    glass_champagne_for_loop(x),
    glass_champagne_map(x),
    glass_champagne_sapply(x),
    glass_champagne_vectorized(x),
    times = 100
)

benchmark_results



benchmark_results %>% 
    summary() %>% 
    kable() %>%
    kable_styling()


The function using the 'for loop' is the most efficient with the lowest average execution time.




#Vectorized version of f 

glass_champagne_vectorized_1 <- function(x) {
  if (!is.numeric(x)) {
    stop("Input must be numeric", call. = FALSE)
  }
  result <- numeric(length(x))
  
  result[x < 0] <- 0
  result[x >= 0 & x < 0.5] <- 15
  result[x >= 0.5 & x < 10] <- 2
  result[x >= 10 & x < 15] <- 8 * log2(x[x >= 10 & x < 15] - 9) + 2
  result[x >= 15 & x < 20] <- 8 * log2(6) + 2
  result[x >= 20] <- 0

  return(result)
}
```

Comment: SO ist designed for single questions.

Comment: I have modified my question.Thanks for the comment.

Comment: "Vectorization" has two meanings (in R). The general meaning: A function accepts a vector as input. The specific meaning: A function accepts a vector as input and loops over this vector in compiled code (usually C or C++ code, without calling an R function in the loop). Only vectorization with the specific meaning improves performance. None of your examples with looping function is vectorization in the specific meaning. If randomness impacts the benchmark comparison, there usually is no significant performance difference.

Comment: Also, four iterations is a joke. Benchmark for a much longer `x` (e.g., `x <- runif(1e5, 0, 100)`.

Comment: The function you call "non-vectorized" is not non-vectorized by standard meanings of the word in the R ecosystem. It performs several vectorized operations. `result[x < 0] <- 0` is a vectorized way to set all values of `result` to `0` when `x < 0`. The non-vectorized equivalent would be `for(i in seq_along(x)) {if(x[i] < 0) result[i] <- 0}`, which as we can see in the `glass_champagne_for_loop` timings is much slower.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, vectorization is when an R function accepts a vector and loops over the vector using compiled code. This blog is a good primer on what that entails. https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/

`dplyr` offers the `case_when` function, a vectorized switch statement. The cases are evaluated sequentially, so if we put some thought into the ordering of the cases, we can express each one more simply, as the portion of the remaining cases we want to capture.

I find this a little easier to read and update (ie no duplication of boundary conditions) than the `vectorized_1` approach which relies on (vectorized) base subsetting, while being only a little slower. Both are around 10-50x faster than the other approaches. Further gains might be possible through use of high-performance packages like `data.table`, `collapse`, `r-polars`, etc., but since there isn't any grouping/filtering/sorting/aggregation, the base R approach is probably most of the way there, optimization-wise.

```
glass_champagne_case_when <- function(x) {
  if (!is.numeric(x)) {
    stop("Input must be numeric", call. = FALSE)
  }

  dplyr::case_when(
    x < 0 ~ 0,
    x < 0.5 ~ 15,
    x < 10 ~ 2,
    x < 15 ~ 8 * log2(x - 9) + 2,
    x < 20 ~ 8 * log2(6) + 2,
    TRUE ~ 0)
}
```

Performance comparision

```
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(1e5, 0, 100) # This produces a 10,000 element vector which will
                        # test all your cases, unlike the original example, which 
                        # only includes 10, 100, 1000, 10000 and only tests the
                        # [10,15) and [20,Inf) conditions
benchmark_results <-  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  glass_champagne_for_loop(x),
  glass_champagne_map(x),
  glass_champagne_sapply(x),
  glass_champagne_vectorized(x),
  glass_champagne_vectorized_1(x),
  glass_champagne_case_when(x),
  times = 10
)
benchmark_results

Unit: milliseconds
                            expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval  cld
     glass_champagne_for_loop(x)  52.960055  53.412731  61.185612  54.574443  58.631885  95.47927    10  b  
          glass_champagne_map(x)  89.964806  95.264066 110.118122 114.428991 118.407187 127.24063    10   c 
       glass_champagne_sapply(x)  98.055716  99.825937 115.203950 105.875980 129.841775 149.90624    10   c 
   glass_champagne_vectorized(x) 241.768219 249.352902 267.312261 266.679526 285.752135 294.72080    10    d
 glass_champagne_vectorized_1(x)   5.157898   5.242335   6.603331   5.327715   5.991626  16.61144    10 a   
    glass_champagne_case_when(x)   7.384915   7.688236   8.448064   8.201550   8.992769  11.16036    10 a
```

By the way, it is entirely normal for benchmark results to vary, since your computer's state (background processes, available memory, etc.) is changing constantly. You can run more iterations (e.g. `times = 100`) to get a larger sample size and thereby less variation in the average from successive benchmarks, but that will take longer.